# "Method has not yet been implemented" exception for appium `HasClipboard()`

Tags: java, appium-android

Below is my code in Java

```
String text = "54321";
((HasClipboard) BaseClass.driver).setClipboardText(text);
TouchAction t=new TouchAction(BaseClass.driver);`
```

Getting Exception for the above code.

Configuration: Selenium-java 3.13.0, Java-client 6.1.0, android-test 2.1.1

Comment: it seems that that method, for that class "has not yet been implemented"

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
I have imported below three packages in my code:
import io.appium.java_client.TouchAction;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidElement;
import io.appium.java_client.clipboard.HasClipboard;

Comment: which doesn't change the answer. You cast your Object to type 'HasClipboard', then try to call 'setClipboardText(...)'. The method itself exists, either in the class, or in it's parent, but hasn't been implemented yet

Comment: Is this what you mean?

`String text = "54321";
HasClipboard clip = ((HasClipboard) BaseClass.driver);
clip.setClipboardText(text);
TouchAction t=new TouchAction(BaseClass.driver);`

Comment: I don't know. all I can do is make assumptions based on the information you provided. Either way, what is happening is explained in my previous comment

Answer (score 0):

It means that Appium server version you are using is not supporting the API call for `POST /wd/hub/session/:session_id/appium/device/set_clipboard`
from appium-java-client you are using.

Notes:

1. Don't set `selenium-java` version explicitly, Appium will handle it on its own. When you import it, you may raise incompatibility issues.
2. Try to install the [latest appium server](https://github.com/appium/appium/releases), and update client library to 7.0.0. There are lots of ongoing changes so `appium/device/set_clipboard` maybe affected

Answer (score 0):

```
start_state = problem.getStartState()
    fringe = util.Stack()
    visited = set()

    # Each item in the fringe is a tuple containing the state and a list of actions
    fringe.push((start_state, []))

    while not fringe.isEmpty():
        current_state, actions = fringe.pop()
        if problem.isGoalState(current_state):
            return actions
        visited.add(current_state)
        successors = problem.getSuccessors(current_state)
        for next_state, action, _ in successors:
                   if next_state not in visited:
                    next_actions = actions + [action]
                    fringe.push((next_state, next_actions))
    return []
USE THIS IT WORKS FOR ME FOR DEPTHFIRSTSEARCH IF ANYBODY WANTS TO DO SAME CODE FOR BREATHFIRSTSEARCH YOU JUST HAVE TO REPLACE STACK WITH QUEUES HAVING THE SAME CODE 
I HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU
```

Comment: please stop screaming and read [/help/formatting](/help/formatting)

Comment: I think you might have posted this answer on the wrong question.